# Why my css does not take effect for a:link ,a:visited, a:hover, a:active?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table, with one column

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td width="30"  class="top-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></td>
     <td width="30" class="top-nav"><a href="#">About</a></td>
     <td width="30" class="top-nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to CSS the column to have mouse hover effect, so I did following:

```
.top-nav a{
   display: block;
   padding: 3px;
   text-decoration: none;

}

.top-nav a:link, .top-nav a:visited{
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #1d5987;

}
.top-nav a:hover, .top-nav a:active{
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #666666;

}
```

But my CSS does not take any effect for `a:link ,a:visited, a:hover, a:active` background and font color change of the table cell, why?

Comment: @DanielA.White is right: http://jsfiddle.net/EDn8p/

Comment: `:visited` is unlikely to work at all, because most modern browsers have disabled it (for security concerns due to the fact that it could be exploited by hackers to learn about a user's browsing history). Beyond that, there's nothing wrong with you CSS code now that you've fixed the hanging commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you remove the extra `,` here

`.top-nav a:visited,`

and

`.top-nav a:active,`

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ZSbdH/

Comment: @Nupul - Daniel White beat everyone (see comment under question). You should upvote this answer if you believe it's a good one.